# Morgan logging not working in keystone app

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, keystonejs

I am running a keystone.js express based app. I am trying to integrate Morgan logging but it is not working when any HTTP requests hit the site. I just see the normal output in my console. What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Here is my `routes/index.js` file

```
var keystone = require('keystone'),
    middleware = require('./middleware'),
    importRoutes = keystone.importer(__dirname);

var morgan = require('morgan');


// Common Middleware
keystone.pre('routes', middleware.initLocals);
keystone.pre('render', middleware.flashMessages);

// Import Route Controllers
var routes = {
    views: importRoutes('./views')
};

// Setup Route Bindings
exports = module.exports = function(app) {

    //Logging
    app.use(morgan('combined'));

    // Views
    app.get('/',middleware.ensureLatestBrowser, routes.views.index);
    app.get('/blog/:category?',middleware.ensureLatestBrowser, routes.views.blog);
    app.get('/blog/post/:post',middleware.ensureLatestBrowser, routes.views.post);
    app.all('/contact', middleware.ensureLatestBrowser,routes.views.contact);
    app.all('/software',middleware.ensureLatestBrowser, routes.views.software);


};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because Keystone already loads an instance of `morgan` (which loads before yours). The default format used by Keystone is `:method :url :status :response-time ms`.

Keystone allows you to customize the format by using the `logger` option.

```
keystone.init({
   ...
   'logger': 'combined'
   ...
});
```

The above example will set the output format for `morgan` to `combined`.

---

**EDIT**

The above is true as of Keystone `0.3.x`, when Keystone migrated to Express `4.x` and `morgan` as the Express logger. Pre-`0.3.x` versions of Keystone use Express `3.x` with `express.logger`.

Comment: According to the keystone.js docs, it does NOT use morgan but express.logger for logging if I set `logger:default` in the init. That is fine, but I need a way to write that output to a file rather than the console.

Comment: Actually, it uses `morgan`. We need to update the docs. I'm submitting a PR do update the docs today.

Comment: I just submitted a PR do update the keystonejs.com docs ([PR #1392](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/pull/1392)).

Comment: So when I set `'logger' : 'combined'` it prints out the word "combined" in the terminal every time I go to any URL on the site rather than the format it should..any ideas?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what version of Keystone are you using?

Comment: "version": "0.2.42" - I cant figure out how to update to the latest. npm update doesnt update keystone to the latest. I have `'auto update': true,` already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77732/discussion-between-randomdeduction-and-jme).